Requesting a reference for the fact that $ SL_{n}(K) $ is perfect
I'm looking for a reference for the fact that the special linear group $\operatorname{SL}_{n}\left(K\right)$ ($n \ge 2$) is perfect (i.e., it is the commutator subgroup of itself) over a field $K$ if $\# K > 3$ or $n>2$.
Of course, the proof for the fact is easily found on the internet. However, I want a source that I can refer like a book but not a website.

This is Theorem 1.7 and Theorem 1.9 in the textbook "Classical Groups and Geometric Algebra" by Larry C. Grove. (There are probably many other references you could use for this.)

Thank you so much.

This is Lemma 2, of Section 6.7 in Nathan Jacobson's Basic Algebra I. On page 377 in my edition (printed in 1985).

Thank you for the reference.

Thanks for the edit @peterag. Sloppy of me not to include the chapter + section. I only remembered the page as I had deleted a comment with identical content :-)
